# python scipy.stats.binomtest pvalue gives unexpected ratio in randomized tests

Tags: binomial-distribution

When conducting an experiment, the `p value` is the chance that the experiment's result was obtained by chance given the null hypothesis.

I wrote a few lines of code to check if `scipy.stats.binomtest` gives this result. Each experiment executes 20 bets with 0.1 chance of success for each. I ran 20,000 experiments, and found the the percentage of those with `p value < 0.02` was not 0.02 but closer to 0.011.
Assuming that the Python implementation is correct, and there is a valid statistical reason for this result - what is it?

Here's my code:

```
def single_experiment(p, n):
    return [random.random() < p for i in range(n)]

def run(experiments, bet_success_rate):
    random.seed(datetime.now())
    num_bets_in_exp = 20
    pval_threshold = 0.02
    noisy_exp = 0

    success_chances = {}
    bets = {}
    stats = []
    pvals = []
    for _ in tqdm(range(experiments)):
        exp = single_experiment(bet_success_rate, num_bets_in_exp)
        res = binomtest(sum(exp), num_bets_in_exp, p=bet_success_rate, alternative="greater")
        pval = res.pvalue
        if pval < pval_threshold:
            noisy_exp += 1

    print(noisy_exp / experiments)
```

And here's a screenshot with the results:[image]

Comment: The problem stems from the fact that 20 is a too low number of trials. In the line `num_bets_in_exp = 20` change 20 for 2,000 for example, and see the difference. Too bad the question has been closed. You should edit your question (or create a new one) to get a detailed explanation as to why the results are different with 20 and 2,000 bets (it would be unquestionably a statistics question, not a programming one, so it shouldn't be closed this time).

Comment: Thanks. 2000 still gives me a lower result than expected, but higher than 20 samples.